# Can a Powershell hashtable be accessed via .Key rather than ["Key"] somehow?

Tags: powershell, syntax, hashtable

I'm a lazy programmer, and all this hash["Key"] punctuation is getting on my nerves. Is there a syntactic sugar (perhaps a different object type) that allows you to create hashtables that are accessed using member method syntax (hash.Key)? There are many easy hacks to do this in Ruby. Is there a hack to do this in Powershell?

Comment: It talking about Dictionary, etc, there may be useful information here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577488/does-powershell-have-a-method-missing (I looked for "powershell method_missing", which is how Ruby ostruct and similar work.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
$hash = @{"a" = 1; "b" = 2 }
$val = $hash.a
```

NOTE: It's also something that works on any IDictionary, not just Hashtables.

Comment: +1 because it does answer the question as presented. However, I wonder if there is similar support for common CLR types (such as Dictionary, or other indexable Collection, which might be returned from calling a method) ..

Comment: Damn, I'm stupid. I was failing, but because I trying to use it within string expansion, without using $(). I apologize for the inane question. I was referring to hashes @pst, not Dictionaries, though I appreciate your faith in my not asking a stupid question... I just failed by doing my first testing using bad syntax: "Expand ${hash.key}" rather than "Expand $($hash.key)". I hadn't tested it outside of string expansion.

Comment: Fun times... this works fine everywhere but where I was initially testing it. `$ExecutionContext.InvoteCommand.ExpandString('$($hash.key)')` fails. But the same command, passed '$($hash[''key'']' succeeds.